# Need helping converting some method from C# to VB.net (Windows Phone 7)

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

Hi I am looking at some example codes online regarding an app I am trying to make. However as it is in C# I have to convert it to VB.net as thats the language I need to use. The following methods I have not really seen before so I dont know how to convert them. I tried using online converting tools but they seem to give me codes full of errors (I dont think it recognises the format)

```
Play += (_, __) =>
{
//Do something here
};

camRecorder.Initialized += (___, ____) =>
{
//Do something here
};

new Thread(() =>
{
//Do something here
}).Start();
```

I would really appreciate it if someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: *However as it is in C# I have to convert it to VB.net as thats the language I need to use.*  Why? Can you not use an assembly compiled from C# within an app written in vb.net?

Comment: it is a vb.net project so I cannot use c#

Comment: Well, I think you can reference an assembly that is compiled from C#.

Comment: Thanks to the magical CLR, this should be true.

Comment: How can I acheieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated code, hope this will be ok.

```
AddHandler Play, Sub(_, __)
'Do something here
End Sub

AddHandler camRecorder.Initialized, Sub(___, ____)
'Do something here
End Sub

New Thread(Sub()
'Do something here
End Sub).Start()
```

Comment: @Matt9Atkins the code looks right to me, except that `'Do something here` should be between the `Do` and `End Function` bits, not after `End Function`  The C# code is using lambda expressions; the VB code is using anonymous methods.  What doesn't look right to you?

Comment: Most of converter can't convert c# delegates to vb.net properly e.g rptPages.ItemCommand += this.rptPages_ItemCommand; can't translate to
AddHandler rptPages.ItemCommand, AddressOf Me.rptPages_ItemCommand, there may be such issue here.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking. How would I sort this out?

Comment: I tried just the first method and I get the following error - Nested sub does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub RoutedEventHandler(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)'.

Comment: The methods go inside the Public Sub New() method